# Cannot read property 'packery' of undefined` when using Isotope and Webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack, packery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to use the packery layout mode in Isotope with webpack.

Current setup:

- jQuery version that comes with Wordpress
- Coffeescript
- Modified [Gulp Starter](https://github.com/vigetlabs/gulp-starter)

Here's the file where I'm calling the packery layout of isotope.

```
Isotope = require 'isotope-packery'

iso = new Isotope '.js-isotope',
  # main isotope options
  itemSelector: '.js-isotope__item'
  # set layoutMode
  layoutMode: 'packery'
  packery:
    gutter: 10
```

I keep getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'packery' of undefined`. Here's the full console and reference in the file.

[image]

I'm new to Webpack / requiring modules so I may be missing something obvious.

Here's my webpack config file:

```
var config = require('../config')
if(!config.tasks.js) return

var path            = require('path')
var webpack         = require('webpack')
var webpackManifest = require('./webpackManifest')

module.exports = function(env) {
  var jsSrc = path.resolve(config.root.src, config.tasks.js.src)
  var jsDest = path.resolve(config.root.dest, config.tasks.js.dest)
  var publicPath = path.join(config.tasks.js.dest, '/')
  var filenamePattern = env === 'production' ? '[name]-[hash].js' : '[name].js'
  var extensions = config.tasks.js.extensions.map(function(extension) {
    return '.' + extension
  })

  var webpackConfig = {
    externals: {
      // require("jquery") is external and available
      //  on the global var jQuery
      "jquery": "jQuery"
    },
    context: jsSrc,
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
      })
    ],
    resolve: {
      root: jsSrc,
      extensions: [''].concat(extensions)
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader?stage=1',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
          test: /isotope\-|fizzy\-ui\-utils|desandro\-|masonry|outlayer|get\-size|doc\-ready|eventie|eventemitter/,
          loader: 'imports?define=>false&this=>window'
        },
        // https://github.com/metafizzy/packery/issues/239#issuecomment-144992512
        {
          test: /.js$/,
          loader: 'imports?define=>false',
          include: /(fizzy\-ui\-utils|outlayer|get\-size|packery)[\\\/]/
        },
        {
          test: /\.coffee$/,
          loader: "coffee-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.(coffee\.md|litcoffee)$/,
          loader: "coffee-loader?literate"
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  if(env !== 'test') {
    // Karma doesn't need entry points or output settings
    webpackConfig.entry = config.tasks.js.entries

    webpackConfig.output= {
      path: path.normalize(jsDest),
      filename: filenamePattern,
      publicPath: publicPath
    }

    if(config.tasks.js.extractSharedJs) {
      // Factor out common dependencies into a shared.js
      webpackConfig.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          name: 'shared',
          filename: filenamePattern,
        })
      )
    }
  }

  if(env === 'development') {
    webpackConfig.devtool = 'source-map'
    webpack.debug = true
  }

  if(env === 'production') {
    webpackConfig.plugins.push(
      new webpackManifest(publicPath, config.root.dest),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    )
  }

  return webpackConfig
}
```

**As an aside I can't get the isotope jQuery plugin to be recognised either.**
Calling `$('.grid').isotope()` results in an `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).isotope is not a function` error. I'm not sure if they are related in any way; even though I've referenced jQuery `$ = require 'jquery'`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue was with `require`ing some additional modules. I couldn't find this in the documentation anywhere.

```
require 'jquery-bridget'
require 'isotope-packery'
isotope = require 'isotope-layout'

$grid = $('.l-masonry').isotope()
```

- Bridget needs to be installed to patch the jQuery plugin interface for Isotope [when using RequireJS modules](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#requirejs-pkgd-jquery).
- `isotope-packery` needs to be required *as well as* `isotope-layout` in order to use the Packery options.